# How can I switch the bluetooth state of my phone by changing a file?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth

Let me explain :
I have a phone on Android 4.0.4 with a bluetooth issue. Everytime the bluetooth is on, the phone crashes and reboot. It does that until during one reboot, the bluetooth bugs and fail to start. I don't realy care about bluetooth, so the easy way is to disable it. But everytime my phone starts, it tries to launch the bluetooth again, because somewhere, there is a file, saying "the bluetooth is on" and this file is read by the OS when starting. I'm looking for this file.

For aditional information, I'll say that I already looked everywhere in the phone obtions and stuff, but everything is "dissable" because the bluetooth state is currently on "starting".

Thanks for reading my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this file is `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` (`global/bluetooth_on` value). If so, you can try the following command: `adb shell settings put global bluetooth_on 0` and reboot the device or edit the data base directly with `sqlite3`. Not sure about the first option, for the second root is required.
If this Bluetooth crash is not native for your system, you can also try to find it source by analysing kernel and logcat logs.

Comment: Well... Hum... Seems my phone isn't rooted after all...
Do any of you still have a tool to root an Xperia Arc S in ICS 4.0.4 ?